# Android Base64 encode and decode return null in Unit Test

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, junit, android-testing

I am attempting to decode a Base64 encoded string in Android using the http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Base64.html class.

Both the encodeToString and decode methods are returning null, and I have no idea what's wrong, here's my code for the decode:

```
// Should decode to "GRC"
String friendlyNameBase64Encoded = "R1JD";

// This returns null
byte[] friendlyNameByteArray = Base64.decode(friendlyNameBase64Encoded, Base64.DEFAULT);

// Fails with NullPointerException
String friendlyName = new String(friendlyNameByteArray, "UTF-8");
```

I'm running Android API 23.1.0

Comment: Could you please post the logcat messages? BTW, I was successful in getting the decoded string, i.e., GRC from the code that you have posted.

Comment: So, up until now I have only been running this code from a unit test. I have just ran the app for real and it appears to be working. Any idea what might be going wrong in the unit test?

Comment: Possibly due to use of unitTests.returnDefaultValues=true

Comment: I think that is it !

Comment: I don't understand why it is causing a problem? Just had a suspicion...

Comment: My understanding is that normally android api calls throw exceptions during unit tests, setting returnDefaultValues to true causes them to behave as normal, so why the difference?

Comment: Not entirely sure, but I guess the unit test does not have access to  `android.util.Base64` class and hence returns `null`. Maybe this link will help you http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/unit-testing-support.

Comment: From what I'm reading, it actuall just causes API calls to return null or zero instead of throwing exception. I guess that I will have to write it as an instrumentation test instead, thanks for your help!

Comment: using code from the android libraries during unit testing is a know issue.  Even if you set "returnDefaultValues" to true, that returns things like null (for objects) and 0 (for ints).  It's especially annoying, especially for non androidy code like Base64 class.

Answer (score 31):

I had the same problem in my unit tests. I didn't realize the Base64 class I'm using is a part of the Android API, therefore

**You can't use android.util.Base64 in a regular JUnit test, it must be an Instrumentation test.**

However, if you really want it as a unit test, you could use the Apache Commons Base64 class instead. Include it in Gradle build:

```
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-collections4
compile group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-collections4', version: '4.1'
```

And then slightly different usage,

- Base64.[encodeBase64String(byte[] binaryData)](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64.html#encodeBase64String(byte[]))
- Base64.[decodeBase64(String base64String)](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64.html#decodeBase64(java.lang.String))

Comment: compile group: 'commons-codec', name: 'commons-codec', version: '1.9'
was the dependency that worked for me.

Comment: Curses in binary

Answer (score 10):

You can use the Robolectric Runner

1. Add the dependency in your `build.gradle`:

   ```
   testCompile 'org.robolectric:robolectric:X.X.X'
   ```
2. Add this line in your testing class:

   ```
   import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
   import org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner;

   @RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)
   public class MyTestingClassTest {
       ...
   }
   ```

Comment: this is the correct way to do it. even in 2023 this should be the accepted answer!

Answer (score 5):

Follow up o android tutorials and unit test notes while you need just Unit tests without use of some android libs

In your case you're depending on android.Base64. I had similar issue and moving test classes from `src/test` -> `src/androidTest` worked. Those tests are run on virtual machine or real android device. I didn't notice the diff at the first look.

Comment: greaet answer but i simple write new test in androidTest

Answer (score 5):

As discussed, android.util.Base64.decode is returning a null in test harness because of this setting in the build file:

```
testOptions {
    unitTests.returnDefaultValues = true
}
```

To avoid including other libraries you could fall back on java.util.Base64, which is only available in Java8 and on Android 26 and above. If you already target 26+ then just switch to this method, but if you have to target earlier SDKs you could check for the null return and call a test-harness method instead:

```
// Required because Android classes return null in desktop unit tests
@TargetApi(26)
private fun testHarnessDecode(s : String) : ByteArray {
    return java.util.Base64.getDecoder().decode(s)
}
```

I would rather do this than pull in additional library dependencies, but YMMV.

Comment: The java.util.Base64.getEncoder().encode(byteArray) returns null even when encode returns something; however, if I use encode(byteArray).toString() it's an invalid Base64 string for decoding

Answer (score 2):

What works with me is to mock Base64.decode method using mockk

```
 mockkStatic(Base64::class)
 every { Base64.decode(any<String>(),Base64.DEFAULT) } returns byteArrayOf()
```

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up doing was a wrapper.  I allow the android.util.Base64 to fail and then if we are on build greater than "O" or equal to 0 (zero. meaning not an android device or no android sdk version).

```
 class Base64Wrapper {
    companion object {
        fun encodeToString(input : ByteArray) : String {
            return try {
                Base64.encodeToString(input, Base64.DEFAULT)
            } catch (e :Exception) {
                if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O || android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT == 0) {
                    java.util.Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(input)
                } else {
                    throw e;
                }
            }
        }

        fun decode(input: String) : ByteArray {
            return try {
                Base64.decode(input, Base64.DEFAULT)
            } catch (e :Exception) {
                // if build is greater or equal to "O" or is equal to 0 (zero) which means it is not a device (i.e. unit test).
                if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O || android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT == 0) {
                    java.util.Base64.getDecoder().decode(input)
                } else {
                    throw e;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```