# different code's behavior in unit test and in runtime

Tags: android, kotlin

The same code works in runtime and doesnt work in test

There is such code

```
private fun generatePrivateKeyFromText(key: String): Key {
    val kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA")
    val keySpecPKCS8 = PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(Base64.decodeBase64(key))
    return kf.generatePrivate(keySpecPKCS8)
}
```

When I run or debug app it works ok, but this code fails on **generatePrivate** while **testing**

```
java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException: java.security.InvalidKeyException: IOException : algid parse error, not a sequence
```

---

```
@Test
fun decrypt() {
    val encrypt = "MoRxCpLJNqxfXGVeU73zZFi+X2j2TLUTyIn1XRqCoEfeN8rNBR/YrEtumAz+8/0AaEsvx0+qTilfbw+edZd8Wfum4McWQ8oWXifvWLgoXybhxWUmCdi2fwA9Gw0parY6CSNYUDA2UuLrLLaDGMz/Jj4s4XmXKp5zuec1zXVdrPM="
    val prkey = "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"
    val decrypt = CryptoService.decrypt(encrypt, prkey)
    assertEquals("Pika-pika", decrypt)
}
```

---

```
fun decrypt(ciphertext: String, key: String): String {
    var decodedBytes: ByteArray? = null
    try {
        val c = Cipher.getInstance("RSA")
        c.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, generatePrivateKeyFromText(key))
        decodedBytes = c.doFinal(Base64.decodeBase64(ciphertext))

    } catch (e: Exception) {
        Log.e("Crypto", "RSA decryption error: $e")
    }
    return String(decodedBytes ?: ByteArray(0))
}
```

---

Working function is in Fragment

```
 private fun testCrypto() {
        val encrypt = "MoRxCpLJNqxfXGVeU73zZFi+X2j2TLUTyIn1XRqCoEfeN8rNBR/YrEtumAz+8/0AaEsvx0+qTilfbw+edZd8Wfum4McWQ8oWXifvWLgoXybhxWUmCdi2fwA9Gw0parY6CSNYUDA2UuLrLLaDGMz/Jj4s4XmXKp5zuec1zXVdrPM="
        val prkey = "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"
        val decrypt = CryptoService.decrypt(encrypt, prkey)
        println(decrypt) // "Pika-pika"
    }
```

I call it on *onViewCreated*

---

**Updated:**

I added BC provider (thanks, @JamesKPolk)

```
private fun generatePrivateKeyFromText(key: String): Key {
    Security.addProvider(BouncyCastleProvider())
    val kf = KeyFactory.getInstance(algorithm)
    val keySpecPKCS8 = PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(Base64.decodeBase64(key))
    return kf.generatePrivate(keySpecPKCS8)
}
```

But it is still **ok in runtime** and **not while testing**

```
javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Decryption error
```

So problem for different running code didnt go.

What the difference between runtime and test which crashes code?

Comment: ah, but that's a different error than the 1st one.

Comment: And again only in unit test. I rewrote text and header so.

Comment: I use org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64 . The case about it is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33847781/android-base64-encode-and-decode-return-null-in-unit-test)

Comment: ahhh, so the unit tests don't really run on Android.

Comment: But problem is not in android dependency. javax.crypto doesnt want to work correctly

Comment: See my latest edits to my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that the private key is **not** a PKCS8EncodedKeySpec, but rather an RSAPrivateKey object from PKCS#1. The BC provider, however, will still decode this mistake without complaint. However, other providers will rightfully complain. My guess is that the runtime is using an older version of Android where the default provider is BC, but your test is using a newer version where that isn't the case.

The fix is to make your private key a proper PKCS8EncodedKeySpec. Alternatively, you can explicitly request the "BC" provider. To do so, you need to specify "BC" in the getInstance() call: `val keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA", "BC")`

However, note that it appears that [BC provider support is on its way out](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2018/03/cryptography-changes-in-android-p.html).

To convert a private key in the PKCS#1 format, either wrap a 'BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY'-style header and footer around the base64 blob or decode the base64 blob and place that in a file, then run:

```
openssl pkcs8 -topk8 -in privkey.pem  -outform der -nocrypt | openssl base64 -A
```

or

```
openssl pkcs8 -topk8 -in privkey.der -inform der -nocrypt  | openssl base64 -A
```

A second issue comes from relying on defaults. Instead of doing

```
val c = Cipher.getInstance("RSA")
```

which gets you defaults for mode and padding and thus is non-portable, always specify the full "*algorithm/mode/padding*" transformation string to `Cipher.getInstance()`. In you case, it appears the data is not padded (an insecure mode) you'd need something like

```
val c = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/NoPadding")
```

However, you really should use proper randomized padding, and currently that is OAEP padding.

**Summary**

The runtime environment is Android, but I think the test environment is Oracle Java (or maybe openjdk). There are evidently two critical differences in those environments:

1. Android uses the BC provider for KeyFactory which will handle private keys encoded in PKCS#1 RSAPrivateKey format. Oracle Java only supports PKCS8 encoded keys.
2. In Android, `Cipher.getInstance("RSA")` defaults to `Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/NoPadding")`, but Oracle Java defaults to `Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding")`

Comment: I have just checked on 4th Android and the last. Runtime is still working. So I dont think that the reason in versions

Comment: I will try to experiment with your code but I'm not a Kotlin programmer.

Comment: It helped. But I still dont understand why the same code works in runtime and doesnt work while testing

Comment: I'll add that info to the answer. Let me know if it still remains unclear.